# Android web page upload cannot choose some pdf files

Tags: android, pdf, web, webview, upload

When upload file from Android browser to a web page, do not know why cannot choose some of the pdf files.

Anyone has any idea no it?

Thanks.

Comment: More Specific ? I assume it is webview , had you ```.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);```? In order the basic script to work in webViIew . Or I didnt understand that correctly?

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa: both webview and browser has the same situation, some pdf files are dimmed (disabled to select).

Comment: Oh This problem. Very Common.  for webview you need this `.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`.